# If I link to an internal PDF file in Media Wiki, how can I prevent thumbnail display for PDFs?

Tags: pdf, mediawiki

With a syntax like this ...

```
[[File:foo.pdf]]
```

... it is possible to refer to a file in a MediaWiki page. In this case a thumbnail is generated from the first PDF page and displayed in the rendered view of the page.

My question is: How do I prevent this thumbnail generation and present some PDF specific icon instead? (A single icon for all PDF files?)

Comment: You can also use `[[Media:foo.pdf]]` which will create a direct link to the PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the display of the thumbnail by just making it a link to the file, by prepending a colon:

```
[[:File:foo.pdf]]
```

However, then you won't get any icon.

To replace this with an icon, you need to specify which icon to use. For example, if you have Instant Commons turned on:

```
[[File:Document-pdf.svg|25px|link=foo.pdf]]
```

To use this for all files, I'd suggest wrapping it up in a template, so you can call it with `{{PDF|foo.pdf}}`. Create `Template:PDF` containing:

```
[[File:Document-pdf.svg|25px|link={{{1}}}]]
```

This way, you could also display the filename as well if you wanted to:

```
[[File:Document-pdf.svg|25px|link={{{1}}}]] [[:File:{{{1}}}|{{{1}}}]]
```

Comment: Yes, I remember that with the colon, but I do not get an icon of course. I hoped there would be some kind of configuration option or syntactical argument I was not aware of. Thank you for your suggested solution based on a template: This is a very interesting solution! I'll try this!

Comment: Nope, nothing built-in; basically anything like this one is expected to do with templates I think. (Oh, and don't forget to mark this question as answered, if it is.) :-)